# How to set Spark configuration for Databricks SQL Endpoint

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-sql

I know how to set Spark configuration in a regular Databricks compute cluster. But I didn't see any place to set it in Databricks SQL endpoint.

Comment: what spark configurations do you want to set?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I am trying using `alter table ... rename to ...` in Databricks SQL on S3 and it throws exception. I would like to try setting `spark.databricks.delta.alterTable.rename.enabledOnAWS` to `true`.

Comment: @Haojin
what is the error you are getting?  When I tried the following on DBSQL (SQL editor) it worked without any errors.

alter table table_name1 rename to table_name2;

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran are you running Databricks SQL on S3 or other blob storage? The issue is specific to Databricks on S3/AWS.